# Why am I getting a different output when the multiplication of the digit is above 10?

Tags: python, arrays, multiplication

```
#card number
card = input('Number: ')

j = int(card[::2]) # this will jump character by 1
# multiplying each other number by 2
j *= 2
print(j)
```

So whenever I run this code and input e.g. 1230404

The output would be correct which is 2688

But when I input for example 1230909 the output is 2798, I expected 261818

Comment: You are doubling the decimal number 1399, so your answer is correct but your expectation is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what your code is doing.

1. You slice every second character from your input string, so `'1230909'` becomes `'1399'`.
2. You convert that to a single `int`, `1399`.
3. You multiply that number by `2`, producing `2798`.  I assure you that the computer did the math correctly.

It appears what you expected was for each digit to be doubled individually.  To do that, you need to convert each digit, double it, and combine them back.  Python has great facilities for this, I'd suggest a generator expression inside a `join` call.